# Unable to access model using cancan gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, spree, spree-auth-devise

I am using Spree to build an e-commerce application.I have created one model Offer(Spree::Offer) . I have created one role seller,and I am trying to give seller access to view,update and manage this model(Offer) in the admin panel using the following code

> if user.respond_to?(:has_spree_role?) and user.has_spree_role?('supplier')     > can :manage,Offer

But when I login as seller,I am unable to see Offers Tab in the Admin Panel
But,when I login as admin ,I am able to see Offers Tab.Admin has following access

> can :manage,:all

I am new to rails, Should I do anything prior, to get the desired result

Comment: I am not sure if it will solve your problem, however if you are using cancan, consider switching to https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the ability like this as the offer model is under the spree module then and then you can access the Spree::Offer recourse.

```
if user.respond_to?(:has_spree_role?) and user.has_spree_role?('supplier') 
  can :manage, Spree::Offer
end
```